# How to change the NSAccentColorName of an app during runtime with conditions?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, appkit

I saw that NSAccentColorName right-under the root node of the Info.plist can change the application accent color to your specified color in an Xcode asset file.

Is this possible to control this parameter dynamically during the runtime whenever you want the change?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be technically impossible as of Nov 29, 2021, according to a comment in the repository of Transmission app: [Closed
Choice of Accent color may not be ideal on macOS
#2205](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/issues/2205#issuecomment-981717595)

However, If SwiftUI, one may use `View.tint(SwiftUIColor)` to override the accent color of the specified View.